# How to show linq result to a partial view and refresh partial view based on button click in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, updatepanel, partial-views

I have a page with on the left side contains list of Jobs and right side contains a partial view to show details of the selected job (partial view only show when the user click on a job), but I can't pass selected jobs Id and not get it in my partial view.

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {

            var selectedjob = db.Postings.ToList();
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                 selectedjob = db.Postings.Where(p => p.PostingId == id).ToList();
                ViewBag.sss = selectedjob;
                return PartialView("_JobDetails", selectedjob);
            }

            return View("Index", selectedjob);
            //return View(db.Postings.ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For refreshing partial view (Selected job details), you need to make an ajax call.

For e.g.

Lets say below is your jobs listing html.

```
    <ul>
       <li>
          <a hre="javascript:;" data-jobid="1" class="job-desc">Job 1 </a>              
       </li>
       <li>             
          <a hre="javascript:;" data-jobid="2" class="job-desc">Job 2 </a>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

Lets assume your jquery click event of Job titles as -

```
 $(document).on('click', '.job-desc', function () {
    var JobId = $(this).data('jobid'); // This will get the clicked job's Id

    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Index","Home")",
        type: 'post',
        dataType:"HTML", // as we will be returning Partial view
        data: { id: JobId },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#job-details').html(data); // assuming that your job details is under "job-details" as div id
        }
    });
});
```

Now your action result in Home controller will look like -

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? id)
    {
        var selectedjob = db.Postings.ToList();
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
             selectedjob = db.Postings.Where(p => p.PostingId == id).ToList();
             ViewBag.sss = selectedjob;

        }
        return PartialView("_JobDetails", selectedjob);
    }
```